# How to return an object along with a sub object in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am trying to display a camera object along with its most recent state. I am able to display camera and the most recent timestamp, but am struggling to access the corresponding state field.

I have the following Django models.

```
class Camera(models.Model):

   name = models.CharField(max_length=32)


class TimeStamp(models.Model):

   camera = models.ForeignKey(Camera, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   state = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   timeStamp = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True, auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
```

And I have the following view.

```
def index(request):
  context = {
    'cameras': Camera.objects.all().annotate(latest_timestamp=Max('timestamp__timeStamp')),
    'functional': Camera.objects.annotate(latest_timestamp=Max('timestamp__timeStamp')).filter(latest_timestamp=F('timestamp__timeStamp'), timestamp__state=True),
    'faulty': Camera.objects.annotate(latest_timestamp=Max('timestamp__timeStamp')).filter(latest_timestamp=F('timestamp__timeStamp'), timestamp__state=False),
   }

return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

And in my index.html I have

```
<table class="table table-hover">
<thead class="text-info">
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Current State</th>
    <th></th>
</thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for camera in cameras %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ camera.id }}</td>
                <td>{{ camera.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ camera.latest_timestamp }}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
```

Instead of camera.latest_timestamp, I would like to show the corresponding state field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would define my `Camera` model this way:

```
class Camera(models.Model):

   name = models.CharField(max_length=32)

   @property
   def latest_state(self):
       latest_timestamp = self.timestamp_set.latest('timeStamp')
       return latest_timestamp.state
```

And use it in the template as

```
{% for camera in cameras %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ camera.id }}</td>
    <td>{{ camera.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ camera.latest_state }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

I did not test it.

Answer (score 1):

Because each `camera` may have multiple `state`s you cannot simply do `{{ camera.state }}`.

Instead do the following:

```
{% for camera in cameras %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ camera.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ camera.name }}</td>
        {% for timestamp in camera.timestamp %}
            <td>{{ timestamp.state }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This would show all of the states. I need to just get the most recent state. EDIT: I just tried this and it actually does nothing?